# Python: Read multiple large csv's at the same time

Tags: python, csv

I have 9 large CSVs (12GB each), with exactly the same column structure and row order, just different values in each csv.
I need to go through the csv's row by row and compare the data inside them, but they are far too large to store in memory.
Row order being maintained is highly important as the row position is used as an index for comparing the data between csvs, so appending the tables together isn't  ideal.

I'd rather avoid 9 nested "with open() as csv:" using DictReader and this seems very messy.

I've tried to used pandas and concatenate:

```
files = [list_of_csv_paths]
result = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files], ignore_index=True)
```

but it simply tries to load all the data into memory and I don't have nearly enough RAM.
Changing the pd.read_csv to have a specific chucksize returns a TypeError.

I've seen that possibly Dash could be used for this but I'm not experienced with Dash.

I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: do not use `with` statement with 9 elements. Just open 9 files, just with `open` function and at the end close files. Itere over files simulatenesly

Comment: It sounds like `pandas` is the wrong tool; see the `csv` module and process row by row.

Comment: @Francis So what you are saying is: you need to compare first row in 9 files, then second row in the same 9 files etc?

Comment: Yeah, @Leemosh I'm just trying to get this to be as efficient as possible, each csv has 40m+ rows and ~60 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a good start - reading by chunks - where `chunksize` is number of lines by [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-chunking). That should be the best way of reading huge files. You can try to use threading as well to process it faster.

Simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
chunksize = 10 ** 8
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    process(chunk)
```

Check the `skiprows` parameter as well. Next example is gonna read lines from 1000 to 2000.

Example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=',', header=None, skiprows=1000, chunksize=1000)
```